# Cannot trigger SQL request in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a form that the user can use to update an object. The object has 5 img attributes. So at modification i want to update the database. I want the function to only update the images (attributes in the database (img, img2,img3,img4,img5) that the user changed in the form.

Here is the update function on form submit :

```
public function updateOutil()
    {

        $o = new Outillage($_POST["art"]);
        $o->__set("id", $_POST["id"]);
        $o->__set("id_art", $_POST["id_art"]);
        $o->__set("article", $_POST["art"]);
        $o->__set("id_doc", $_POST["id_doc"]);
        $o->__set("document", $_POST["doc"]);
        $o->__set("ilot", ilot::findAllByName($_POST["ilot"]));
        $o->__set("emplacement", $_POST["emplacement"]);
        $o->__set("liste_tubes", $_POST["liste_tubes"]);

        define('TARGET', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'imageOutil/'); // Repertoire cible
        define('MAX_SIZE', 5300000); // Taille max en octets du fichier
        define('WIDTH_MAX', 5000); // Largeur max de l'image en pixels
        define('HEIGHT_MAX', 5000); // Hauteur max de l'image en pixels
// Tableaux de donnees
        $tabExt = array('jpg','gif','png','jpeg'); // Extensions autorisees
        $infosImg = array();
// Variables
        $extension = '';
        $nomImage = '';
        $message='';
        $cpt='';
        /************************************************************
         * Creation du repertoire cible si inexistant
         *************************************************************/
        if( !is_dir(TARGET) ) {
            if( !mkdir(TARGET, 0755) ) {
                exit('Erreur : le répertoire cible ne peut-être créé ! Vérifiez que vous diposiez des droits suffisants pour le faire ou créez le manuellement !');
            }
        }
        /************************************************************
         * Script d'upload
         *************************************************************/
        if(!empty($_POST['image']))
        {
// On verifie si le champ est rempli
            if( !empty($_FILES['fichier']['name']) )
            {
// Recuperation de l'extension du fichier
                $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['fichier']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// On verifie l'extension du fichier
                if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$tabExt))
                {
// On recupere les dimensions du fichier
                    $infosImg = getimagesize($_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name']);
// On verifie le type de l'image
                    if($infosImg[2] >= 1 && $infosImg[2] <= 14)
                    {
// On verifie les dimensions et taille de l'image
                        if(($infosImg[0] <= WIDTH_MAX) && ($infosImg[1] <= HEIGHT_MAX) && (filesize($_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name']) <= MAX_SIZE))
                        {
// Parcours du tableau d'erreurs
                            if(isset($_FILES['fichier']['error'])&& UPLOAD_ERR_OK === $_FILES['fichier']['error']){
// On nomme le fichier
                                $nomImage=$_POST['image'];
//On verifie qu'aucun fichier du même nom existe
                                if(!file_exists (TARGET.$nomImage)) {
// Si c'est OK, on teste l'upload
                                    try{
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $nomImage);
                                        $o->__set("image", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage); //TARGET . $nomImage => D:/Documents and Settings/raphael.delric/Mes documents/Mes Outils Personnels/*/UwAmp/www//imageOutil/*
                                        $message1= '<br/>L\'opération a été effectuée avec succès!';
                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur systeme
                                        $o->__set("image", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage . time());
                                        $message1= '<br/>Problème lors de l\'enregistrement de l\'image 1 !';
                                        $message1.= $e->getMessage();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $newNomImage=  date('His',time()). $nomImage;
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $newNomImage);
                                    $o->__set("image", 'imageOutil/' .  $newNomImage);
                                    $message1= '<br/>Un fichier image du même nom que image 1 est déjà existant.';
                                    $message1.= '<br/>L\image a donc été enregistrée comme suis [heures:minutes:secondes][votre nom de fichier].[votre extension]. '.$newNomImage;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $message1= '<br/>Une erreur interne a empêché l\'enregistrement de l\'image';
                                $message1.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
// Sinon erreur sur les dimensions et taille de l'image
                            $message1= '<br/>Erreur dans les dimensions de l\'image !';
                            $message1.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
// Sinon erreur sur le type de l'image
                        $message1= '<br/>Le fichier à uploader n\'est pas une image !';
                        $message1.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour l'extension
                    $message1= '<br/>L\'extension du fichier est incorrecte ! Extension attendue : .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg';

                }
            }
            else
            {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour le champ vide
                $message1= '<br/>Pas de Fichier ajouté pour l\'image 1 !';
                $cpt.='A';
            }

        }
        else{
            $message1= '<br/>Vous n\'avez pas nommez l\'image 1 !';
        }
        $message=$message1;
        if(!empty($_POST['image2']))
        {
// On verifie si le champ est rempli
            if( !empty($_FILES['fichier2']['name']) )
            {
// Recuperation de l'extension du fichier
                $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['fichier2']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// On verifie l'extension du fichier
                if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$tabExt))
                {
// On recupere les dimensions du fichier
                    $infosImg = getimagesize($_FILES['fichier2']['tmp_name']);
// On verifie le type de l'image
                    if($infosImg[2] >= 1 && $infosImg[2] <= 14)
                    {
// On verifie les dimensions et taille de l'image
                        if(($infosImg[0] <= WIDTH_MAX) && ($infosImg[1] <= HEIGHT_MAX) && (filesize($_FILES['fichier2']['tmp_name']) <= MAX_SIZE))
                        {
// Parcours du tableau d'erreurs
                            if(isset($_FILES['fichier2']['error'])&& UPLOAD_ERR_OK === $_FILES['fichier2']['error']){
// On nomme le fichier
                                $nomImage=$_POST['image2'];
//On verifie qu'aucun fichier du même nom existe
                                if(!file_exists (TARGET.$nomImage)) {
// Si c'est OK, on teste l'upload
                                    try{
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier2']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $nomImage);
                                        $o->__set("image2", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage); //TARGET . $nomImage => D:/Documents and Settings/raphael.delric/Mes documents/Mes Outils Personnels/*/UwAmp/www//imageOutil/*
                                        $message2= '<br/>L\'opération a été effectuée avec succès!';
                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur systeme
                                        $o->__set("image2", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage . time());
                                        $message2= '<br/>Problème lors de l\'enregistrement de l\'image 1 !';
                                        $message2.= $e->getMessage();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $newNomImage=  date('His',time()). $nomImage;
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier2']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $newNomImage);
                                    $o->__set("image2", 'imageOutil/' .  $newNomImage);
                                    $message2= '<br/>Un fichier image du même nom que image 2 est déjà existant.';
                                    $message2.= '<br/>L\image a donc été enregistrée comme suis [heures:minutes:secondes][votre nom de fichier].[votre extension]. '.$newNomImage;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $message2= '<br/>Une erreur interne a empêché l\'enregistrement de l\'image';
                                $message2.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
// Sinon erreur sur les dimensions et taille de l'image
                            $message2= '<br/>Erreur dans les dimensions de l\'image !';
                            $message2.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
// Sinon erreur sur le type de l'image
                        $message2= '<br/>Le fichier à uploader n\'est pas une image !';
                        $message2.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour l'extension
                    $message2= '<br/>L\'extension du fichier est incorrecte ! Extension attendue : .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg';

                }
            }
            else
            {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour le champ vide
                $message2= '<br/>Pas de Fichier ajouté pour l\'image 2 !';
                $cpt.='B';
            }

        }
        else{
            $message2= '<br/>Vous n\'avez pas nommez l\'image 2 !';
        }
        $message.=$message2;
        if(!empty($_POST['image3']))
        {
// On verifie si le champ est rempli
            if( !empty($_FILES['fichier3']['name']) )
            {
// Recuperation de l'extension du fichier
                $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['fichier3']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// On verifie l'extension du fichier
                if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$tabExt))
                {
// On recupere les dimensions du fichier
                    $infosImg = getimagesize($_FILES['fichier3']['tmp_name']);
// On verifie le type de l'image
                    if($infosImg[2] >= 1 && $infosImg[2] <= 14)
                    {
// On verifie les dimensions et taille de l'image
                        if(($infosImg[0] <= WIDTH_MAX) && ($infosImg[1] <= HEIGHT_MAX) && (filesize($_FILES['fichier3']['tmp_name']) <= MAX_SIZE))
                        {
// Parcours du tableau d'erreurs
                            if(isset($_FILES['fichier3']['error'])&& UPLOAD_ERR_OK === $_FILES['fichier3']['error']){
// On nomme le fichier
                                $nomImage=$_POST['image3'];
//On verifie qu'aucun fichier du même nom existe
                                if(!file_exists (TARGET.$nomImage)) {
// Si c'est OK, on teste l'upload
                                    try{
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier3']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $nomImage);
                                        $o->__set("image3", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage); //TARGET . $nomImage => D:/Documents and Settings/raphael.delric/Mes documents/Mes Outils Personnels/*/UwAmp/www//imageOutil/*
                                        $message3= '<br/>L\'opération a été effectuée avec succès!';
                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur systeme
                                        $o->__set("image3", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage . time());
                                        $message3= '<br/>Problème lors de l\'enregistrement de l\'image 1 !';
                                        $message3.= $e->getMessage();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $newNomImage=  date('His',time()). $nomImage;
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier3']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $newNomImage);
                                    $o->__set("image3", 'imageOutil/' .  $newNomImage);
                                    $message3= '<br/>Un fichier image du même nom que image 3 est déjà existant.';
                                    $message3.= '<br/>L\image a donc été enregistrée comme suis [heures:minutes:secondes][votre nom de fichier].[votre extension]. '.$newNomImage;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $message3= '<br/>Une erreur interne a empêché l\'enregistrement de l\'image';
                                $message3.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
// Sinon erreur sur les dimensions et taille de l'image
                            $message3= '<br/>Erreur dans les dimensions de l\'image !';
                            $message3.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
// Sinon erreur sur le type de l'image
                        $message3= '<br/>Le fichier à uploader n\'est pas une image !';
                        $message3.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour l'extension
                    $message3= '<br/>L\'extension du fichier est incorrecte ! Extension attendue : .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg';

                }
            }
            else
            {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour le champ vide
                $message3= '<br/>Pas de Fichier ajouté pour l\'image 3 !';
                $cpt.='C';
            }

        }
        else{
            $message3= '<br/>Vous n\'avez pas nommez l\'image 3 !';
        }
        $message.=$message3;
        if(!empty($_POST['image4']))
        {
// On verifie si le champ est rempli
            if( !empty($_FILES['fichier4']['name']) )
            {
// Recuperation de l'extension du fichier
                $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['fichier4']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// On verifie l'extension du fichier
                if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$tabExt))
                {
// On recupere les dimensions du fichier
                    $infosImg = getimagesize($_FILES['fichier4']['tmp_name']);
// On verifie le type de l'image
                    if($infosImg[2] >= 1 && $infosImg[2] <= 14)
                    {
// On verifie les dimensions et taille de l'image
                        if(($infosImg[0] <= WIDTH_MAX) && ($infosImg[1] <= HEIGHT_MAX) && (filesize($_FILES['fichier4']['tmp_name']) <= MAX_SIZE))
                        {
// Parcours du tableau d'erreurs
                            if(isset($_FILES['fichier4']['error'])&& UPLOAD_ERR_OK === $_FILES['fichier4']['error']){
// On nomme le fichier
                                $nomImage=$_POST['image4'];
//On verifie qu'aucun fichier du même nom existe
                                if(!file_exists (TARGET.$nomImage)) {
// Si c'est OK, on teste l'upload
                                    try{
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier4']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $nomImage);
                                        $o->__set("image4", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage); //TARGET . $nomImage => D:/Documents and Settings/raphael.delric/Mes documents/Mes Outils Personnels/*/UwAmp/www//imageOutil/*
                                        $message4= '<br/>L\'opération a été effectuée avec succès!';
                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur systeme
                                        $o->__set("image4", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage . time());
                                        $message4= '<br/>Problème lors de l\'enregistrement de l\'image 1 !';
                                        $message4.= $e->getMessage();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $newNomImage=  date('His',time()). $nomImage;
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier4']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $newNomImage);
                                    $o->__set("image4", 'imageOutil/' .  $newNomImage);
                                    $message4= '<br/>Un fichier image du même nom que image 4 est déjà existant.';
                                    $message4.= '<br/>L\image a donc été enregistrée comme suis [heures:minutes:secondes][votre nom de fichier].[votre extension]. '.$newNomImage;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $message4= '<br/>Une erreur interne a empêché l\'enregistrement de l\'image';
                                $message4.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
// Sinon erreur sur les dimensions et taille de l'image
                            $message4= '<br/>Erreur dans les dimensions de l\'image !';
                            $message4.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
// Sinon erreur sur le type de l'image
                        $message4= '<br/>Le fichier à uploader n\'est pas une image !';
                        $message4.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour l'extension
                    $message4= '<br/>L\'extension du fichier est incorrecte ! Extension attendue : .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg';

                }
            }
            else
            {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour le champ vide
                $message4= '<br/>Pas de Fichier ajouté pour l\'image 4 !';
                $cpt.='D';
            }

        }
        else{
            $message4= '<br/>Rien pour l\'image 4 !';
        }
        $message.=$message4;
        if(!empty($_POST['image5']))
        {
// On verifie si le champ est rempli
            if( !empty($_FILES['fichier5']['name']) )
            {
// Recuperation de l'extension du fichier
                $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['fichier5']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// On verifie l'extension du fichier
                if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$tabExt))
                {
// On recupere les dimensions du fichier
                    $infosImg = getimagesize($_FILES['fichier5']['tmp_name']);
// On verifie le type de l'image
                    if($infosImg[2] >= 1 && $infosImg[2] <= 14)
                    {
// On verifie les dimensions et taille de l'image
                        if(($infosImg[0] <= WIDTH_MAX) && ($infosImg[1] <= HEIGHT_MAX) && (filesize($_FILES['fichier5']['tmp_name']) <= MAX_SIZE))
                        {
// Parcours du tableau d'erreurs
                            if(isset($_FILES['fichier5']['error'])&& UPLOAD_ERR_OK === $_FILES['fichier5']['error']){
// On nomme le fichier
                                $nomImage=$_POST['image5'];
//On verifie qu'aucun fichier du même nom existe
                                if(!file_exists (TARGET.$nomImage)) {
// Si c'est OK, on teste l'upload
                                    try{
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier5']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $nomImage);
                                        $o->__set("image5", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage); //TARGET . $nomImage => D:/Documents and Settings/raphael.delric/Mes documents/Mes Outils Personnels/*/UwAmp/www//imageOutil/*
                                        $message5= '<br/>L\'opération a été effectuée avec succès!';
                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur systeme
                                        $o->__set("image5", 'imageOutil/'. $nomImage . time());
                                        $message5= '<br/>Problème lors de l\'enregistrement de l\'image 1 !';
                                        $message5.= $e->getMessage();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    $newNomImage=  date('His',time()). $nomImage;
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichier5']['tmp_name'], TARGET . $newNomImage);
                                    $o->__set("image5", 'imageOutil/' .  $newNomImage);
                                    $message5= '<br/>Un fichier image du même nom que image 5 est déjà existant.';
                                    $message5.= '<br/>L\image a donc été enregistrée comme suis [heures:minutes:secondes][votre nom de fichier].[votre extension]. '.$newNomImage;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $message5= '<br/>Une erreur interne a empêché l\'enregistrement de l\'image';
                                $message5.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
// Sinon erreur sur les dimensions et taille de l'image
                            $message5= '<br/>Erreur dans les dimensions de l\'image !';
                            $message5.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
// Sinon erreur sur le type de l'image
                        $message5= '<br/>Le fichier à uploader n\'est pas une image !';
                        $message5.= '<br/>L\'enregistrement de l\'image n\'a donc pas été pris en compte.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour l'extension
                    $message5= '<br/>L\'extension du fichier est incorrecte ! Extension attendue : .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg';

                }
            }
            else
            {
// Sinon on affiche une erreur pour le champ vide
                $message5= '<br/>Pas de Fichier ajouté pour l\'image 5 !';
                $cpt.='E';
            }

        }
        else{
            $message5= '<br/>Rien pour l\'image 5 !';
        }
        $message.=$message5;
        $o->updateImg($cpt);
        header('Location: /Site.php?a=outillage&b='.urlencode($message));
    }
```

And here is the updateImg function that is supposed execute the sql request as follow:

```
public function updateImg($cpt){
        $c=Base::getConnection();
        $posA=strpos($cpt,'A');
        $posB=strpos($cpt,'B');
        $posD=strpos($cpt,'C');
        $posE=strpos($cpt,'D');
        $posF=strpos($cpt,'E');
        $q='UPDATE outillage SET id_art=:id_art, article=:article, id_doc=:id_doc, document=:document, ilot=:ilot, emplacement=:emplacement, liste_tubes=:liste_tubes';

        if ($posA===false) {
            $q.=", image=:image";
        }
        if ($posB===false){
            $q.=", image2=:image2";
        }
        if ($posD===false){
            $q.=", image3=:image3";
        }
        if ($posE===false){
            $q.=", image4=:image4";
        }
        if ($posF===false){
            $q.=", image5=:image5";
        }
        $q.="WHERE id=:id;";

        $query=$c->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':id',$this->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':id_art',$this->id_art,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':article',$this->article,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':id_doc',$this->id_doc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':document',$this->document,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':ilot',$this->ilot,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':emplacement',$this->emplacement,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':liste_tubes',$this->liste_tubes,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($posA===false){
            $query->bindParam(':image',$this->image,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($posB===false){
            $query->bindParam(':image2',$this->image2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($posD===false){
            $query->bindParam(':image3',$this->image3,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($posE===false){
            $query->bindParam(':image4',$this->image4,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($posF==false){
            $query->bindParam(':image5',$this->image5,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $query->execute();
```

I get no errors. But when i test those, i get the right "message" from updateOutil() but my database is not updated. I think it is a problem about how i "build" my SQL request.

I search around and couldn't find any helpful topic. As i'm stuck on this since several hours, any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: I advise you to refactor those 5 (probably) identical image update codes to get rid of all those nested ifs, and make it a function you call 5 times.

Comment: So far it has nothing to do with PhpStorm itself. But I would still advise to add space before `WHERE` in this line: `$q.="WHERE id=:id;";` And yes -- just like @Tincho.UY have suggested -- dump your variables just before you will execute your SQL and look for errors. Right now the issue could be in missing space as suggested above.

Comment: I agree with @LazyOne. I think you're missing a space before the WHERE clause in your query.

Comment: @LazyOne , I tried it as is just by curiosity, and you were right it was the missing space before the WHERE.

Comment: And @Oli I was aware that this was not the best way to do, i did what you advised just made a function with one parameter (that is the file number) and i call it in a for{}. Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to watch your variables and debug your application. If something is wrong you should get at least an exception.

Comment: Great piece of advice for the rest of my project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a solution. I think there must be some rules about prepared query that i didn't follow because what i need to do was to to create separate query for each image and upload them separatly. So in my updateImg() function in now have for each if condition

```
if ($posA===false){
            $query=$c->pepare('UPDATE outillage SET image:=image WHERE id:=this')
            $query->bindParam(':id',$this->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':image',$this->image,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute()
        }
```

After all my ifs i update the other attributes normally